# Generate several colored background for one cell based on the input of different Hex value on a different cell?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, hex

In other words, when `00FF00` is typed in cell A1, cell B1's formula turns it into `#00FF00`, which automatically highlights cell B1 with the corresponding color. The first time it works.

Yet, once cell A1's hexadecial value is manually changed to another color like `FF0000`, cell B1 does automatically change the value to `#FF0000` but not the background --> the previous background remains (in this case `#00FF00`).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following script code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var c = ss.getActiveCell();
  if( s.getName() == 'Sheet1' && c.getA1Notation() == 'A1' )
  s.getRange('B1').setBackground( '#' + c.getValue() );
};
```

**Note:** In the above code change the sheet name "Sheet1" and also cells "A1" & "B1" as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kishan, It works but only one color at the time and it turns only "Red", "Blue" or "Green". I have actually 3 cells A1+A2+A3 which returns 1 Hex value result in B1. With this code, shades and degrees are not shown: `00FF00` (A1+A2+A3) will return the right color but `00FF3F` (still A1+A2+A3) will not and furthermore it will set the wrong colored background cell -- in this particular case, `00FF3F` will turn Blue (should be greenish).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that works but I need to input the Hex values manually to get the background color to appear automatically --> for the moment, a hex value in B1 resulting from a formula (with A1+A2+A3 cells in it) will only work one time (then, what ever Hex value be changed, the cell B1 keeps its previous background color even though the Hex value in the cell -B1, changes).

```
// regex for hex color codes
HEX_COLOR_REGEX = /(^#[0-9A-Fa-f]{3}$)|(#[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}$)/;

// column to watch for changes (i.e. column where hex color codes are to be entered)
HEX_CODE_COLUMN = 5; // i.e. column A

// column to change when above column is edited
HEX_COLOR_COLUMN = 5; // i.e. column B

// utility function to test whether a given string qualifies as a hex color code
function hexTest(testCase) {
  return HEX_COLOR_REGEX.test(testCase);
}

function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow();
  var column = range.getColumn();
  if (column === HEX_CODE_COLUMN) {
    var values = range.getValues();
    values.forEach( function checkCode(rowValue, index) {
      var code = rowValue[0];
      if (hexTest(code)) {
        var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row + index, HEX_COLOR_COLUMN);
        cell.setBackground(code);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }
    });
  }
}
```